# Role based authentication system fastify

Tags: node.js, authentication, roles, fastify

I'm currently working on a fastify project, where I use fastify-jwt to create Bearer tokens to my users.

And in the routes I acces it with following:

```
fastify.get(
    "/test",
    {
        preValidation: [fastify.authenticate],
    },
    Collection.functionX
);
```

So know I want some routes not accessible for "normal" users, only for "admin" users. Normally this information is within the token. I can grand access to only admins within the function, by I want to directly not give access to the route. So it directly calls "not allowed".

I found fastify Guard but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has been around for a long time. But I'll leave my solution here:

```
//import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify';
//import { findOneUser } from '../services/userService';

const checkRole = (roles: string[]) => async (
    request: FastifyRequest,
    reply: FastifyReply,
    next: () => void
): Promise<void> => {

    const userId = request.user.id;
    const user = await findOneUser({ id: userId });

    if (!user)
        return reply.status(401)
            .send({ success: false, error: 'Unauthorized' });

    const roleExists = roles.some(role => role === user['role']);

    if (!roleExists) 
        return reply.status(401)
            .send({ success: false, error: 'Unauthorized' });
    
    return next();
};
```

Import the checkRole function and use it in the route you want (include this in preHandler).

Answer (score 1):

I just worked implementing, and I would like to leave my approach here in case someone else might find it useful.

Fastify has great plugins to achieve both, authentication and authorization. Authorization is to verify you are who you say you are, and authorization is validation that you have access to a resource depending on who you are.

I found the most scalable and maintainable approach is to use plugins. The plugins I used are:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fastify/auth
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fastify/jwt

For authentication with JWT you can create a plugin like this:

```
import fastifyPlugin from 'fastify-plugin';
import fastifyJwt, { FastifyJWTOptions } from '@fastify/jwt';
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify';

export default fastifyPlugin<FastifyJWTOptions>(async (fastify) => {
    fastify.register(fastifyJwt, {
        secret: '',
        decode: { complete: true },
        sign: { algorithm: 'RS256', expiresIn: '1h' },
        decoratorName: 'jwtUser',
    });

    fastify.decorate(
        'authenticate',
        async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
            try {
                await request.jwtVerify();
            } catch (error) {
                throw fastify.httpErrors.unauthorized();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Then, for authorization you would create another plugin like this:

```
import fastifyPlugin from 'fastify-plugin';
import auth, { FastifyAuthPluginOptions } from '@fastify/auth';
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply, FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';

export default fastifyPlugin<FastifyAuthPluginOptions>(
    async (fastify: FastifyInstance) => {
        fastify.register(auth);

        fastify.decorate(
            'authorize',
            async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {

                const allowedRoles = request.routeOptions.config.allowedRoles;

                if (allowedRoles && request.jwtUser.payload.user) {
                    const userRoles = request.jwtUser.payload.user
                        ? request.jwtUser.payload.user.roles
                        : [];

                    if (!allowedRoles.some((role: any) => userRoles.includes(role))) {
                        throw fastify.httpErrors.unauthorized();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

And you would call them from the routes you need them like this:

```
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify';

const root: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
    fastify.get(
        '/',
        {
            schema: {},
            onRequest: [fastify.authenticate],
            config: { allowedRoles: ['admin'] },
            preHandler: fastify.auth([fastify.authorize]),
        },
        (request, reply) => {
            return reply.code(200).send('Welcome!')
        }
    );
};

export default root;
```

From the Fastify docs, authentication is better done earlier on the lifecycle to prevent DOS attacks. Authorization can be done later on like in the preHandler step. The values of the roles would be passed on the options.config of the route where you need the authorization checked like in the example above.

For the decorators added for authorization and for authentication you might need to extend Fastify types. You can do it like this:

```
import 'fastify';
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify';
declare module 'fastify' {

    /**
     * Type function to extend FastifyInstance to work with hook authentication
     * onRequest: [fastify.authenticate] defined at src\plugins\jwtVerification.ts
     */
    type Authenticate = (
        request: FastifyRequest,
        reply: FastifyReply
    ) => Promise<void>;

    /**
     * Type function to extend FastifyInstance to work with hook authentorization
     * preHandler: fastify.auth([fastify.authorize]) defined at src\plugins\roleBasedAutorization.ts
     */
    type Authorize = (
        request: FastifyRequest,
        reply: FastifyReply
    ) => Promise<void>;

    /** Apply the extension */
    interface FastifyInstance {
        authenticate: Authenticate;
        authorize: Authorize;
    }

    /**
     * Interface to extend FastifyContextConfig, so the allowedRoles property can be added to
     * the options.config object in routes using authorization
     */
    interface FastifyContextConfig {
        allowedRoles?: string[];
    }
}
```

This example is general, and covers both authorization and authentication checks on selected routes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use firebase authentication or any ,and put the user in a data base with a schema has property "role",then check this role in middleware,for example if role==0 its admin and so on .

Comment: How can I do this within the route?